# Maintain sync of select list

Tags: javascript, jquery

My objective has been to build a custom dropdown like the one on Amazon's search scope selector. I do this by positioning a styleable element on top of a standard select list. I then use jQuery to keep the styleable element in sync with the select list. My code works fine, but I would love to learn how to do it cleaner. Currently, I do the syncing twice - on page load and on change. Is it possible to refactor my code using on()? (or similar).

`prev()` is the styleable element.

```
// Sync is performed on page load
var $select = $('select');
$select.each(function(index, value) {
  var optionText = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
  $(this).prev().text(optionText);
});

// Sync is performed on change event
$('select').change(function() {
  var optionText = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
  $(this).prev().text(optionText);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rewriting the code you can just trigger the change event after you bind it which will cause it to sync on page load

```
$('select').change(function() {
  var optionText = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
  $(this).prev().text(optionText);
}).trigger('change'); // <-- trigger change
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a bit too heavyweight for your task, but have you considered using [knockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) for it? It's a quite powerful MVVM javascript framework that uses the notion of [Observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) to keep UI in sync with underlying data model.